# JQuery Scripts are not working on asp.net mvc partial views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I am facing problems inside my asp.net mvc web application's partial views. as jQuery scripts will not work on partial views,, while they work on regular views.
For example i have the following script, while will show the returned partial views inside modal popups:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

            $('#myModalContent').css({ "max-height": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    //height: 1000,
                    //width: 1200,
                    //resizable: true,
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
```

and i added links such as , for the above script to work on , inside my Razor views:-

```
 <a data-modal='' href="@Url.Action("Delete","SecurityRole",new{id = item.SecurityRoleID })"   id="@item.SecurityRoleID" title="Delete">
```

and the action method is :-

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {

SecurityRole securityrole = await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.FindSecurityRole(id.Value);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {

                return PartialView(securityrole);
            }
            return View(securityrole);
        }
```

now let say i have the `<a data-modal=''`link inside a WebGrid, then when i click on the link when the WebGrid first load, the script will cause the partial view to display inside a model popup, without any problems. but if i do some ajax-based paging or sorting inside the WebGrid, and i click on the `<a data-modal=''` link ,, then the script will not fire and the `<a data-modal=''` link will be sending normal http request to the action method, and accordingly a normal view will be returned. so can anyone adivce how to force the above jQuery to understand partial views that are rendered after the jQueryscrip load?

**Problem #2**
I am working on an asp.net mvc 5.2.2 web application. and i wrote the following Script which show a partial view inside a model popup, and also apply an auto complete:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        //$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e){
            $('#myModalContent').css({ "max-height": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    //height: 1000,
                    //width: 1200,
                    //resizable: true,
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
                bindForm(this);
                $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
                    var target = $(this);
                    target.autocomplete({
                        source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000



                    });

                });
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
    $(function () {

        //$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        $(document).on('click', 'button[data-dismiss]', function (e) {
            location.reload();
        });


    });
    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $('.btn.btn-primary,.btn.btn-danger').prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#progress').show();
            if ($(this).valid()) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                       if (result.ISsuccess) {
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#progress').hide();
                            $('.btn.btn-primary,.btn.btn-danger').prop("disabled", false);
                            location.reload();
                            //  alert('www');
                        } else {

                            $('#progress').hide();
                            $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                            $('.btn.btn-primary,.btn.btn-danger').prop("disabled", false);
                            bindForm();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.btn.btn-primary,.btn.btn-danger').prop("disabled", false);
                $('#progress').hide();
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

the field that will apply autocomplete looks as follow:-

```
<h3 style="color:#f99406" >Assign Customers To Skill</h3>

     @using (Html.BeginForm("AssignSingleCustomerToSkill", "Skill"))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group"> 
    @Html.Hidden("ID")
<label class = "control-label col-md-2" >Customer Name</label>
<div class="col-md-10 ">
***<input  name="term" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required= "Please enter a value." class="form-control" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Customer")"  />*** 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="term" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
</div>              


      <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Assign Single Customer" /> </div></div>

</div>

    }
```

now when i render the partial view inside a model popup , and i start typing inside the autocomplete field, the autocomplete action method will be called, and using the F12 developer tool i can see that the response will be received, But the problemis that no items will be displayed inside the auto complete field.

[image]

while if i render the view a regular view (not as partial view), i will not face ant problem.

here is the css i am referencing inside the layout view:-

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssTemplate").Include(
  "~/css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" ,
"~/css/charisma-app.css",
"~/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
"~/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css",
"~/bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css",
"~/bower_components/colorbox/example3/colorbox.css",
"~/bower_components/responsive-tables/responsive-tables.css",
"~/bower_components/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css",
"~/css/jquery.noty.css",
"~/css/noty_theme_default.css",
"~/css/elfinder.min.css",
"~/css/elfinder.theme.css",
"~/css/jquery.iphone.toggle.css",
"~/css/uploadify.css",
"~/css/animate.min.css",
           "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",            
              "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",            
              "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"   ,
              "~/Content/site.css"
                ));
```

can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Comment: You need event delegation. Use `$(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e) { ...` in the main view (replace `document` with the closest ancestor element that contains all the `a[data-modal]` elements)

Comment: thanks a lot i changed the selector to be " $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e){ " and it i working well,, but not sure what do u mean by >>replace document with the closest ancestor element that contains all the a[data-modal] elements<<

Comment: `document` is the top level object, so its just a little more efficient to restrict to to the closest ancestor, so if you have (say) `<div id="container"> in the main view in which you render the partial(s), then it would be `$('#container').on('click', 'a[data-modal]'...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot for the reply it worked well, but i have similar problem with this script selector (where the script will not work on newly added partial views ): "$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {" so i am not sure if i can add an event delegation to the :- "$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {"  as i did to the "$(document).on('click', "??

Comment: No reason it should not work but you would need to post some code if its not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have added a Problem2 section inside my original question, i assume that both talks about the relatively same problem (jQuery scripts does not work on partial views)

Comment: I've been looking at some of your previous questions relating to this and I'm becoming more and more confused with what your doing. For example your `bindForm()` function can call itself (in the `else` block) potentially creating an endless loop, and in the `if` block you call `location.reload();` to reload the page (is that what your intending?). And you potentially have a problem with calling repeatedly `$("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {` if you have already generated any autocomplete's previously (your should destroy any existing autocomplete's first)

Comment: Am I right in assuming you have some kind of grid, and that you have an edit button where you want to display a form that allows you to edit the values in that row and save it? If so, I suggest you could simplify all this by including the form in the main view when you first render it and do something [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5m4fvfv/) - no re-parsing validators, no removing and rebinding controls, no ajax calls to get the data (only to save) etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the reply,, it will be hard if i add all the related code, but what i have inside the modal , is an autocomplete field , which allow users to assign Customer to skills. so users can start typing the customer name and an auto complete will happen . this is the auto complete filed "***<input  name="term" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required= "Please enter a value." class="form-control" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Customer")"  />*** " .

Comment: now if i render a partial view inside the modal no auto complete results will be displayed , although the auto complete action method will be called and the returned json will be received by the browser. while if i render the same view as regular view everything will work well... so seems there is something (maybe css issue) that is preventing the returned json which reaches the browser from being displayed as autocomplete list .....

Comment: Unlikely to be a css issue (and if you right click and inspect the element you would at least see the generated html even if something was causing it to be hidden or not display).

Comment: @StephenMuecke you mean to inspect the html for the partial view ? i did not get ur point sorry...

Comment: I meant in the browser, type "c" in the autocomplete element, then right click on it and then click 'Inspect element'. If you see some html below it (e.g. a `ul` element with some `li` items) then maybe its a css issue. But I think that's unlikely. More likely there will be no `li` items which means its not populating.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i inspected the element of firefox and i get the following:- <div class="col-md-10 "> <input autocomplete="off" name="term" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a value." class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input valid" data-autocomplete-source="/skill/Customer/AutoComplete" type="text"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="term" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div> . so i am not sure what does autocomplete="off" mean? and from where it have been set as this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke but even when i am rendering the view as regular view (non-partial) the autocomplete will be set to "off" also, but the autocomplete functionality will be working well.,,

Comment: finally i got this working, seems the autocomplete result was displayed behinf the modal pop-up, so i add this to the auto complete appendTo: $("#myModal") and now it is working well.